# Play swf file using Embed or Object tag

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to play local swf or flash files on my webpage. I ask client for file input, convert it into data uri and use data uri as source  for embed tag or object tag, but it is not working. Please tell me what is wrong with my code.

HTML

```
<input id="swf_file" type="file" accept="/*" />
<Embed id="swf_player" />
```

Javascript

```
swf_file.onchange = function(){
    var files = this.files;
    var file = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]); 
    swf_player.src = file; 

};
```

Complete HTML

```
<html>
<head><title>Swf File</title></head>
<body>
    <input id="swf_file" type="file" accept="/*" />
    <Embed id="swf_player" />
<script>
swf_file.onchange = function(){
        var files = this.files;
        var file = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]); 
        swf_player.src = file; 

    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for reading...

Comment: > but it is not working. What is happening ? What did you expected ?

Comment: I expected that the swf file will play. but nothing happened.

Comment: @ShivamRana I think that as a manner, that should work, but could you show us all your html ( and js ) code, because surely you have missed something as it's not working ?

Comment: @akmozo I added the complete code.

Comment: @ShivamRana Try it in a different browser, but could you tell us why you want to do that ? You can also try to use [swfobject](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/).